# How does "Use this field's values as search keywords" work with a Matrix field?

Tags: search

I'm fine-tuning a search results page and have noticed that "Use this field's values as search keywords" is included both on the matrix field itself, and within each block type / sub-field. I currently have the matrix field checked, but the Form block type / text field unchecked.

When I search my site using the following code:

```
{% set searchQuery = craft.app.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(searchQuery).orderBy('score').limit(20) %}
```

The content inside the `Text` field of the `Form` block shows up in search results. This seems kind of backwards or broken; it's the main content Matrix field for the site, and there are some fields in there that I want to search by, and some that I don't. How do I achieve this?

Additional question; where is this checkbox actually documented? I can't find a description of what "Use this field's values as search keywords" actually does.
[image: screenshot of a matrix field]

Comment: do you have any further informations to this topic or any feedback from P&T?